# Turn off "new email" sound on boot

Tags: 2.2-froyo

When my Froyo phone is almost finished booting up, it makes a sound to notify me that I have new email.  How can turn this off?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have new email?  Or does it have nothing to do with email beyond being the same sound?

Comment: Yes, I have new email.  The situation is that I have to charge the phone every night and I use it as my morning alarm, so it charges on the nightstand.  My wife is asleep when I come to bed and sometimes when I plug it in, the screen won't turn off unless I reboot it.  The "new email" notification is loud and sometimes wakes my wife.  Bad.

Comment: OK.  You should be able to just click the power button for the screen to shut off, does that not work?

Comment: Sometimes it keeps coming back on, that's when I have to reboot.  After the reboot it'll stay off.

Comment: @user3611 I'm curious what phone you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on the comments above you do need a notification solution.  The obvious one is just to turn off notifications for the email app, or to turn down the volume before you go to bed.  You could also use an app like [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to do the latter automatically based on profiles that you set.  For example you can have it mute notifications when plugged in to charge: http://androidforums.com/1207528-post3.html

Comment: I'd prefer to just turn off email notifications.  How can I do that?

Comment: For the GMail app: Menu button -> More -> Settings -> Select ringtone -> Silent.  Should be similar for any other app.